# I am looking for a way to search a certain word in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking for a way to search a certain word in Oracle SQL Developer.
The table I am using has many packages and procedures.
I would like to search a certain word...
How can I find it?  I can't do CTRL+F in all procedure files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. What "table" are you talking about? A table, as an Oracle object, which contains certain columns and data is stored into it?  What does it have to do with CTRL+F in "all procedure files"? What "files"? Didn't you say you have a "table"? So - could you explain what you really have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this [blog](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/04/searching-source-code-your-views-in-sql-developer/). As mentioned here, you can search for a certain word in the `Find Database Object` section.

[image]